# Unity PlayMaker - Couldn't find Action Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playmaker

I've already posted in PlayMaker forum, but I'm not getting any responses. Hoping someone that had the same problem here would see and shed some light.

I am reviving an old project. It's been left untouched for 5 years. So the Unity version is still in 5.2.1f1 and PlayMaker version 1.7.8.3p2

My problem is I cannot open a Custom Action Script. It is showing Couldn't find Action Script in the error. The script won't show if searched in project folders.

The game runs though, and the other PlayMaker preset ActionScripts I can access.

Wondering if I am missing something? Please see the screenshot below. Thank you

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io79y.png)

Comment: could be that those files are inside a .dll file?

Comment: Is it possible? If so where can I find it. Ugh..

Answer (score 0):

I now have an answer. All the actions were kept inside a single script. Therefore, cannot be searched in the project view. I found it by guessing, but it would be obvious to find it by making a deep file browser search.